# angular chartjs line chart default options

Tags: chart.js, angular10

Wondering if it is possible to have 1 configuration for all line charts that are created using chart.js
Something like :

```
var chartOptions = new Chart.options = options: {
        responsive:true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        
        legend: {
          labels:{
            fontColor : '#01c38c',
          },
          display: true
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
              unit: 'day',
              displayFormats:{
                'day': 'MMM DD',
                'week': 'MMM DD',
                'month': 'MMM YYYY'
              },
              
            },
            gridLines :{
              display: true,
              color: 'grey',
            } 
          }],
           
      }
```

Then inject these options using:

```
this.chart.options = this.chartOptions;
```

I don't want to specify options for multiple charts, as they are the same.
What is the best approach to this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set global default options by using `Chart.defaults.global.optionname`. You will have to do this for every option so the part for your legend default options will look like this:

```
Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.fontcolor = '#01c83c';
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = true;
```

Comment: Chart.defaults.global.scales.xAxes[0].type = 'time' gives me
core.js:5967 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'xAxes' of undefined?

Comment: I thought all options had a default but after logging the defaults  (https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/h7948ov2/4/) you can see not every option has a default. What you can do is call Object.assign(defaultConfig, customConfig) as your option while creating the chart

Comment: But this will also replace the dataset?

Comment: no because you will do it like this new Chart(ctx, {type: type, data: data, options: Object.assign(defaultOptions, SpecifickOptions)})

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for!